# InvalidOperationException Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Hello I'm getting this error:

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
>   'RegistrationMVC.Model.OurDbContext' while attempting to activate
>   'RegistrationMVC.Controllers.HomeController'.

I don't know what may cause it, can be something with dependencies?

startup.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using WebApplicationCore.NetCore.DataAccess;
using WebApplicationCore.NetCore.BusinessLogic;
namespace WebApplicationCore.NetCore
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(env.ContentRootPath)
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: true, reloadOnChange: true)
                .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{env.EnvironmentName}.json", optional: true)
                .AddEnvironmentVariables();
            Configuration = builder.Build();
        }

    public IConfigurationRoot Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        // Add framework services.
        services.AddMvc();

        services.AddSingleton<IConfigurationRoot>(sp => { return this.Configuration; });
        services.AddScoped<IContactDataAccess, ContactDataAccess>();
        services.AddScoped<IContactBusinessLogic, ContactBusinessLogic>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        loggerFactory.AddConsole(Configuration.GetSection("Logging"));
        loggerFactory.AddDebug();

        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            app.UseBrowserLink();
        }
        else
        {
            app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
        }

        app.UseStaticFiles();

        app.UseMvc(routes =>
        {
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "default",
                template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
        });
    }
}
```

[HomeController](https://hastebin.com/ihocixasir.cs)

[OurDbContext](https://hastebin.com/vobelenopu.cs)

Comment: You don't register `OurDbContext` anywhere, which the HomeController's constructor requires. You should also read [ask] and make sure the code _in your question_ is a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Some containers will automatically instantiate a class like OurDbContext (as long as it can be successfully constructed) automatically since it's a type that can be constructed, while others throw an exception if OurDbContext is not defined in the dependency container.  SO it could be as simple as OurDbContext isn't registered and the container acts this way...